# javascript autosubmit form when dropping value into text field

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm having a simple form with just a text field. I'm dropping in values (drag and drop), which works fine (of course), but I want to autosubmit as soon as I've dropped the value into it.

From what I understand 'onchange' wouldn't work, because you need to actually exit the field for it to submit..
Same with 'onmouseup'.. doesn't work either unless I click in the field again...

How can I fix this?

form:

```
<form name="getrdun" action="getrdun" method="post">
Original string: <input type="text" name="origstuff" value=""><br>
<input type=submit value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input) event should do the trick, although note from the reference that there are some problems with IE9 and Opera.

---

**Updated with details:**

Instead of using the `change` event, listen for the `input` event. You don't show any code, so I don't know how you're setting up event listeners, but, e.g. using plain old JavaScript.

```
    inputEl.addEventListener('input', function() {
        // submit the form here...
    })
```

A jQuery version:

```
    $('input[type="text"]').on('input', function() {
        // submit the form here...
    })
```

Obviously, you'll want to select the `<input>` element appropriately.